# Facebook: publish image to page album with app access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**How do I give a Facebook App permission to post images to a Facebook Page album?**

This is the code I use:

```
$args = array(
  'image' => '@' . $img,
  'aid' => $album_id,
  'no_story' => 1,
  'access_token' => $app_access_token
);

$photo = $facebook->api($album_id . '/photos', 'post', $args);
```

This is the error I get:

> Uncaught OAuthException: A user access token is required to request this resource.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use to publish a photo to an album on Facebook. I hope it'll help.

```
<?php    
        include '../src/facebook.php';
        $config['appId']='app_id';
        $config['secret']='API_KEY';
        $config['fileUpload'] = true;

        $param['redirect_uri']='your_redirect_url';
        $param['scope']=',publish_stream,user_photos';

        $facebook=new Facebook($config);
        $userid=$facebook->getUser();

        if($userid){

            try{


  $args = array(
  'image' => '@' . $img,
  'message'=>$message,
);

$photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_id . '/photos', 'post', $args);

    }
    catch(FacebookApiException $e){

       echo $e->getMessage();//Get OAuth Error

    }
    else{
       $loginUrl=$facebook->getLoginUrl($param);
      echo "Please <a href='$loginUrl'>Click Here</a> To Login";
    }


?>
```

Learn more [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/)

Comment: The problem is that I dont know how to get a access_token to allow users to upload images from my app to a fan-page album.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case any user stumbles upon this post , to resolve this error 
1>  $facebook->setaccesstoken() to facebook page's access token . The facebook page access token is available by issuing $facebook->api('/user_id/accounts'), here user id is the id of page's admin .

2> After setting access token you can use the facebook->api to post the photo to album using album id
$facebook->api('album_id/photos', 'post', array( 'source' => '@'.$photo ));